# How to Interpret Multinomial Specification in R's `mnlogit` package

Tags: r, logistic-regression, regression

The `mnlogit` package in R allows for the fast estimation of multinomial logit models.

The specification of forumlas is a bit different from most other regression models/packages in R, however.

Using the `Fish` dataset as a reproducible example,

```
> require(mnlogit)
Loading required package: mnlogit

Package: mnlogit
Version: 1.1.1
Multinomial Logit Choice Models.
Scientific Computing Group, Sentrana Inc, 2013.

> data(Fish, package ='mnlogit')
> head(Fish)
           mode   income     alt   price  catch chid
1.beach   FALSE 7083.332   beach 157.930 0.0678    1
1.boat    FALSE 7083.332    boat 157.930 0.2601    1
1.charter  TRUE 7083.332 charter 182.930 0.5391    1
1.pier    FALSE 7083.332    pier 157.930 0.0503    1
2.beach   FALSE 1250.000   beach  15.114 0.1049    2
2.boat    FALSE 1250.000    boat  10.534 0.1574    2
```

I'm trying to understand the difference between the model specification of

```
fm <- formula(mode ~ 0 + price | income | catch)
```

and

```
fm <- formula(mode ~ 0 + price | income + catch)
```

while the documentation covers the detail of such changes  in the general coeffcient area of the forumla (i.e. where `price` is), I don't see an explanation of how operators like `+` affect the alternative-specific area of the formula/code, relative to `|`.